# Validar fecha c# según el pais

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetimepicker

Hola tengo una app que se encuentra en un servidor de chile y va operar con clientes que están en perú, tengo una validación de fecha con un horario específico pero como hay diferencia de dos horas me genera inconsistencia al validad que puedo usar. estoy usando datetimepicker.

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(model.FechaLlamada) < DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime())
                {
                    ViewBag.msnPost = "Su llamada no a sido agendada. Seleccione una fecha igual o mayor al día y hora actual.";
                    return View(model);
                }
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(model.FechaLlamada).Hour >= 19 || Convert.ToDateTime(model.FechaLlamada).Hour <= 8)
                {
                    ViewBag.msnPost = "Su llamada no a sido agendada. Seleccione una hora entre las 08:00 y las 19:00.";
                    return View(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    new LlamadaDao().create(model);
                    this.Session["msnPost"] = "Su llamada a sido agendada. Usted será llamado.";
                }
```

Comment: Podrias ser mas especifica y dar algunos ejemplos de que problemas estas teniendo?

Comment: Me parece que a lo que se refiere es lo siguiente:

`Hora en chile 13:00 vs Hora en perú 15:00` (no se si en realidad estan dos horas adelante o atrás). Entonces existe error por la hora en la que se realicen diferentes operaciones. Y lo que el quiere es "normalizar" la fecha y hora.

Comment: Si todos tus clientes son de Peru, porque no simplemente le restas dos horas a tus fechas?

Comment: @alanfcm y cuando tenga horario de verano, corre a cambiar el programa?? ;)

Comment: Hay muchas formas de automatizar el proceso.  Se me ocurre guardar una variable en la base de datos y crear un script que maneje cambios de horario.

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo exactamente cual es el problema

Comment: Por lo que entendí el problema es que el servidor maneja el horario de Chile, y las personas que le dan uso son de Perú que maneja una distinta zona horaria, entonces no puede hacer consultas respecto a horarios, asumo yo, que la solución es usar DateTimeOffSet con TimeZoneInfo

Comment: Necesito llamar un cliente en el horario que este indique pero si son las 10:30 (Horario servidor Chile) en Perú son las 8 y el cliente desea que lo contacten a las 10:00 hora Perú, el sistema no lo deja porque entiende que ya el horario pasó. necesito comparar la fecha que ingrese el cliente con el horario actual de Perú.

Comment: No quiero restar horas porque quiero evitar tener que estar haciendo cambios manuales a futuro. por eso quiero decirle a mi aplicativo que entienda que debe comparar fechas con horario Perú.

Comment: @AlexandraTeran Probaste usar la respuesta que te dejé? No te fue de utilidad?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Gracias por tu respuesta, justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar `TimeZoneInfo` y `DateTimeOffset`

```
//Determinar la zona para la conversión
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SA Pacific Standard Time");
//Creo el objeto DateTimeOffset, que recibe como parámetro el DateTime original y el objeto TimeZoneInfo
DateTimeOffset dt_peru = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Convert.ToDateTime(model.FechaLlamada), info);

//Lógica
if (dt_peru.Hour >= 19 || dt_peru.Hour <= 8)
{
    ViewBag.msnPost = "Su llamada no a sido agendada. Seleccione una hora entre las 08:00 y las 19:00.";
    return View(model);
}
else{
//más lógica
}
```

Para obtener más información sobre las posibles zonas horarias que puede recibir como parámetro un TimeZoneInfo les dejo el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c) de stackoverflow en inglés donde se trata dicho tema.

Saludos!

Comment: lo utilicé así, usando tu respuesta y comparando con la fecha actual de perú: DateTimeOffset fechaPeru = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, info);